# Can I trigger a CartoDB infowindow programmatically?

Tags: carto, carto-js

Is it possible to show a CartoDB infowindow for a particular point on a map programmatically? I want to open the info window when a marker is dropped on a Google Map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by simulating a click event, check this example from xavijam here: http://bl.ocks.org/xavijam/ae5317bddf1256f91534

Also, copying his code here for the record:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html, bo

dy, #map {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
      .list {
        position: absolute;
        background: white;
        top: 180px;
        left: 20px;
        padding: 20px;
        z-index: 10;
      }
</style>
```

```
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div class="list">
  <a href="#" class="link">open infowindow</a>

</div>


<script>
  function openInfowindow(layer, latlng, cartodb_id) {
    layer.trigger('featureClick', null, latlng, null, { cartodb_id: cartodb_id }, 0);
  }


  function main() {

    cartodb.createVis('map', 'http://documentation.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/7eb2096a-51d9-11e3-89a7-5404a6a683d5/viz.json', {
        shareable: false,
        title: false,
        description: false,
        search: false,
        tiles_loader: true,
        center_lat: 42,
        center_lon: -3,
        zoom: 6,
        legends: false
    })
    .done(function(vis, layers) {
      // layer 0 is the base layer, layer 1 is cartodb layer
      var layer = layers[1];
      $('.link').click(function() {
        openInfowindow(layer, [40.4000262645, -3.683351686], 5324)
        return false;
      });

    })
    .error(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }

  window.onload = main;
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, plus the hint on the uncompressed JS library.

Comment: Actually, I'm going to edit my response because the non-versioned v3 URLs do no longer contain the last CartoDB.js version :)